# How to plot bivariate density from first principles in R?

Tags: r, pdf, plot, contour, normal-distribution

I am trying to plot the following bivariate density from first principles in R:
[image]

I have attempted to code this using the `sn package`, however it does not work. This is a geometric mixture of the multivariate normal distribution and it is not of the skewing mechanism form that was popularised by A. Azzalini. My code is as follows:

```
library(matlib)

#Make 2-D Grid Coordinates:
number_cor <- 1000 #the number of coordinates
x <- y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out=number_cor) #x and y coordinates
X <- cbind(u=grid2d(x)$x, v=grid2d(x)$y) #combining the coordinates

#Set Parameters:
d<-2
p<-0.75
mu<-as.vector(c(0,0))
cov<-matrix(c(2,0,0,2), nrow=2, ncol=2)

#Summation bounds:
lower <- 1
upper <- 10

#First calculate the density values
mvgsn_pdf_nosum <- function(k, i) {
  ((p*((1-p)**(k-1)))/(((2*pi)**(d/2))*(cov**0.5)*(k**(d/2))))*(exp((-1/(2*k))*(t(i-k*mu))*(inv(cov))*(i-k*mu)))
}
mvgsn_pdf <- sapply(X, 
                  function(i) sum(mvgsn_pdf_nosum(seq(lower, upper, 1), i=i)))
```

The above approach works perfectly in the univariate case. However, my problem arises when I run the `mvgsn_pdf` step in the above code. The density is supposed to look like the following:
[image]

I have never attempted to code a bivariate density from first principles (i.e. hardcoding the PDF). Any help would kindly be appreciated.